# lateinit value is always null or not initialized with MapBox

Tags: android-fragments, kotlin, mapbox

Hello i have an issue with MapBox SDK for android , i use kotlin language in my project and the Viewmap value always came with problem. I'm new in kotlin so maybe i skip something.

i make bottom_navigation_bar so i use fragment to navigate in my application.

my fragment class were i use my variable

```
package com.example.parky.parky_android
import android.app.Application
import android.content.Context
import android.os.Bundle
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.view.ContextThemeWrapper
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.RelativeLayout
import com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.constants.Style
import com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.Mapbox;
import com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.annotations.MarkerOptions;
import com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.geometry.LatLng;
import com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.MapView;
import com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.MapboxMap;
import com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;

class ItemFourFragment : Fragment() {

private lateinit var mapView: MapView

fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?, context: Context, inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    // Mapbox Access token
    Mapbox.getInstance(context, getString(R.string.token_mapbox))
    val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, container ,false)

    mapView = view.findViewById(R.id.mapview)
    mapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    mapView.getMapAsync({
        it.setStyle(Style.SATELLITE)
        // Customize map with markers, polylines, etc.
    })
}

override fun onStart() {
    super.onStart()
    mapView.onStart()
}

override fun onResume() {
    super.onResume()
    mapView.onResume()

}
override fun onPause() {
    super.onPause()
    mapView.onPause()
}
override fun onStop() {
    super.onStop()
    mapView.onStop()

}
override fun onSaveInstanceState(outState: Bundle) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState)
    mapView.onSaveInstanceState(outState)

}
override fun onLowMemory() {
    super.onLowMemory()
    mapView.onLowMemory()

}
override fun onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy()
    mapView.onDestroy()
}

override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
                          savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_item_four, container, false)
}

companion object {
    fun newInstance(): ItemFourFragment {
        val fragment = ItemFourFragment()
        return fragment
    }
}
}
```

And my xml files where i display it :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:mapbox="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".ItemFiveFragment">

<com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.MapView
    android:id="@+id/mapview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    mapbox:mapbox_cameraTargetLat="41.885"
    mapbox:mapbox_cameraTargetLng="-87.679"
    mapbox:mapbox_styleUrl="@string/mapbox_style_satellite"
    mapbox:mapbox_cameraTilt="20"
    mapbox:mapbox_cameraZoom="12"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

and finally the log

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
              Process: com.example.parky.parky_android, PID: 30820
              kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property mapView has not been initialized
                  at com.example.parky.parky_android.ItemFourFragment.onStart(ItemFourFragment.kt:42)
                  at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performStart(Fragment.java:2372)
                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1467)
                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1759)
                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1827)
                  at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:797)
                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManager.java:2596)
                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2383)
                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:2338)
                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:2245)
                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:703)
                  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6938)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                  at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:327)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1374)
```

Do you have any idea what the problem is ?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here:

```
override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
                          savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_item_four, container, false)
}
```

You're returning a view that will be attached to the Fragment and actually displayed.

Here:

```
fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?, context: Context, inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    // Mapbox Access token
    Mapbox.getInstance(context, getString(R.string.token_mapbox))
    val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, container ,false)

    mapView = view.findViewById(R.id.mapview)
    mapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    mapView.getMapAsync({
        it.setStyle(Style.SATELLITE)
        // Customize map with markers, polylines, etc.
    })
}
```

You're inflating a new view that is never being attached to anything. It's also inflating a separate layout, `activity_main.xml`, which I assume does not include a `MapView`.

Instead, you should resolve your `MapView` within `onViewCreated()`, after you've returned your inflated view in `onCreateView()`:

```
override fun onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedState) {
    mapView = view.findViewById(R.id.mapview).apply {
        onCreate(savedState)
        getMapAsync { map -> 
            map.setStyle(Style.SATELLITE)
        }
    }
}
```

You also should not use `lateinit var` for this property, as you're not guaranteed to have a view created (e.g. `onCreateView()` may never be invoked). One instance of this is if your `Fragment` is on the backstack and not user visible. On a configuration change or recreation of the `Activity`, the `Fragment` on the backstack will go through `onCreate()`, but will not create a view. In this case, you would run into a crash in `onStart()` attempting to reference `mapView` that has not been initialized.

Instead, leave it nullable, and perform the operations with `mapView?.doThing()`.

Comment: thanks for your response, that was a part of the problem and i resolve the other part myself.

thanks a lot !